# Performance issue on Service bus queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have huge amount of messages per second sent to my Service bus queue. I am using below code to send messages:

```
var message = new Message(body);

var result = await queueClient.SendAsync(messageOne)
```

I am facing performance issues, is there anything I can do to optimize the code?

P.S. - I have newly joined my company and new to Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk#concurrent-operations) documentation for optimising your code.

Performing an operation (send, receive, delete, etc.) takes some time. This time includes the processing of the operation by the Service Bus service in addition to the latency of the request and the response. To increase the number of operations per time, operations must execute concurrently.

The client schedules concurrent operations by performing asynchronous operations. The next request is started before the previous request is completed. The following code snippet is an example of an asynchronous send operation:

```
var messageOne = new Message(body);
var messageTwo = new Message(body);

var sendFirstMessageTask =
    queueClient.SendAsync(messageOne).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sent message #1");
    });
var sendSecondMessageTask =
    queueClient.SendAsync(messageTwo).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sent message #2");
    });

await Task.WhenAll(sendFirstMessageTask, sendSecondMessageTask);
Console.WriteLine("All messages sent");
```

The following code is an example of an asynchronous receive operation.

```
var receiver = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

static Task LogErrorAsync(Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};

receiver.RegisterMessageHandler(
    async (message, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handle message");
        await receiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    },
    new MessageHandlerOptions(e => LogErrorAsync(e.Exception))
    {
        AutoComplete = false,
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 20
    });
```